# Octave: create .csv files with varying file names stored in a sub folder

Tags: matlab, csv, octave

I have multiple arrays with string data. All of them should be exported into a .csv file. The file should be saved in a subfolder. The file name is variable.

I used the code as follows:

```
fpath = ('./Subfolder/');
m_date = inputdlg('Date of measurement [yyyymmdd_exp]');
m_name = inputdlg('Characteristic name of the expteriment');
fformat = ('.csv');

fullstring = strcat(fpath, m_date,'_', m_name, fformat);
dlmwrite(fullstring,measurement);
```

However, I get an error that FILE must be a filename string or numeric FID

What's the reason?

Best
Andreas

Comment: Have a look at dlmwrite if you want to save as CSV and make sure to create the parent folder first with mkdir. ANd consider creating a minimalistiv sample to show what you want to do and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your goal or problem? The code in your question doesn't have any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I tried to be more specific and implemented some changes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is fairly straightforward for Matlab or Octave.  The first part is creating a file with a filename that changes.  the best way to do this is by concatenating the strings to build the one you want.

You can use:  `fullstring = strcat('string1','string2')`

Or specifically: `filenameandpath = strcat('./Subfolder/FixedFileName_',fname)`

note that because strings are pretty much just character arrays, you can also just use:

fullstring = ['string1','string2']

now, if you want to create CSV data, you'll first have to read in the file, possibly parse the data in some way, then save it.  As Andy mentioned above you may just be able to use dlmwrite to create the output file. We'll need to see a sample of the string data to have an idea whether any more work would need to be done before dlmwrite could handle it.

Comment: you should use "fullfile" to concatenate dir and file which avoids problems with / vs.  \ path separators

Comment: Thank you for the help.

I used the code as follows:

fpath = ('./3_Auswertung/');
m_date = inputdlg('Date of measurement [yyyymmdd_exp]');
m_name = inputdlg('Characteristic name of the expteriment');
fformat = ('.csv');

fullstring = strcat(fpath, m_date,'_', m_name, fformat);
dlmwrite(fullstring,measurement); 

However, I get an error that FILE must be a filename string or numeric FID

What's the reason?